# Tabbed browsing, programmatically navigating to another open tab

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm in a discussion with my co-worker.  We have a web application in a tabbed browsing environment, say with 2 tabs open.  Tab2 has a link to tab1, when I click the link, it opens tab1 in a new tab.  We want to detect if tab 1 is already open, if so then set focus to tab1 (and not open a new window).

He has gotten this working in a broswer window environment, but says it is not possible in a tabbed environment.

Is it possible to for javascript to determine if tab1 is already open and then just set focus to that tab?

Comment: I removed the `java` tag. [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) is **not** the same as [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible if the webbrowser is already **preconfigured** to open links with a target in a new tab instead of new window and sets focus to it *itself* when you have given the links the *same* target name.

E.g.

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="somename">link1</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="somename">link2</a>
<a href="http://xkcd.com" target="somename">link3</a>
```

In other words: you're dependent on the client/webbrowser used. You have no control over it from the server side on.

---

In Firefox for example, the client should have checked both the *Open new windows in new tab instead* and *When I open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately* options to get your requirement to work.

[image]

(as you see, the last one is disabled in mine)

Comment: So there is no function to check what other tabs are open (provided we know they are using tabbed browsing), and what sites those tabs are pointed to?

Comment: if your tab is created by using window.open from the tab you want to check, try window.opener. I do not think you can override the user's tab preference using scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead create a separate document with a DOM-based tab, and iframes pointing to the  real pages. Then you could easily set 'focus' to the correct tab when needed.